# How to write a net with a Memory Data Layer using pycaffe?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

It is possible to write a caffe prototxt in pycaffe with a hdf5 data layer from the following lines:

```
import caffe
from caffe import layers as L

def logreg(hdf5, batch_size):
    n = caffe.NetSpec()
    n.data, n.label = L.HDF5Data(batch_size = batch_size, source = hdf5, ntop = 2)
    n.ip1 = L.InnerProduct(n.data, num_output = 2, weight_filler = dict(type='xavier'))
    n.accuracy = L.Accuracy(n.ip1, n.label)
    n.loss = L.SoftmaxWithLoss(n.ip1, n.label)
    return n.to_proto()

with open('models/logreg_auto_train.prototxt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(logreg('data/train.txt', chunck_size)))
```

Is it possible to use a similar method to write a prototxt that has a Memory Data Layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import caffe
from caffe import layers as L

def logreg(height, width, channels, batch_size):
    n = caffe.NetSpec()
    n.data = L.MemoryData(batch_size = batch_size, height = height, width = width, channels = channels)
    n.ip1 = L.InnerProduct(n.data, num_output = 2, weight_filler = dict(type='xavier'))
    return n.to_proto()

with open('models/logreg_memdata.prototxt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(logreg(128,128,3, chunck_size)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to keep the `n.label` declaration to be able to load in a simple way the weight learned from the previous model. That shouldn't change anything right?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how loading in `n.label` would hurt, but I am surprised that it is required.  Are you using this new network for more training?

Comment: Is there an easy way to set up the weights with a different layer structure? I'm not using it for training indeed, it is just straightforward to set up the weights this way

Comment: When I have switched a network from training to deploy, I am able to remove my **Accuracy** and **SoftmaxWithLoss** layers, then replace my **Data** layer (I used leveldb instead of HDF5) with **MemoryData**.  I have not had a problem loading the weights into my new network from the `*.caffemodel` I trained using my old network.

Comment: What is `L` variable?

Comment: @mrgloom `L` is defined by `from caffe import layers as L`.  I probably should have included that.